# What is the format of the OpenID URL that identifies a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 for .NET Core

My question is what is the format of the OpenID URL that identifies a user?

I have search all the official documentation but I can't find anything

It is supported by IdentityServer4?

Comment: looks like you are searching for [UserInfo endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html#userinfo-endpoint)

Comment: Nope, the UserInfo only gives information about the user only when it is signed in.